# Change the caption in a form in VBA

Tags: forms, excel, auto-update, caption, vba

I have created 2 forms in excel, `userform1` and `userform2`. How do I set the caption of `userform2` so that it displays whatever is in `textbox1` of `userform1` and updates itself when the value of `textbox1` changes?

Comment: The userform has a `Caption` property and the textbox has a `Change` event...

Comment: What do you mean?is it possible?

Comment: Yes - use the textbox's Change event to set the Caption of the other userform - assuming they are both loaded at the same time?

Comment: How?What is the code?

Comment: Do you also want the Caption of `UserForm1` to change when you type text into the `TextBox`

Answer (score 1):

As Rory mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067779/change-caption-in-form-in-vba#comment55888631_34067779) just add it to the `UserForm1` `TextBox1` Change Sub.

Paste the script below into the code part of `UserForm1`.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    'Assign the TextBox Text to a variant
    SomeText = TextBox1.Text
    'Set the UserForm2 Caption to the variant
    UserForm2.Caption = SomeText

End Sub
```

To paste the script into the code part of your `UserForm`, double click the `Userform` in the left side Window of VBA called "Projects Window" then press F7 button on your key board to access the code part of the `UserForm` then paste the code into the bottom of the page.